# Change the Default Date setting in Word 2010

Tags: date, windows-7, formatting, microsoft-word

I am using Word 2010 and Windows 7. You know how when you start typing a date in Word it will automatically suggest what it thinks you want? Like if I start typing “6/29”, a little grey bubble will display “6/29/13 (Press ENTER to Insert)”. How do I get it so the bubble will display the year in a 4 digit format, such as "6/29/2013 (Press Enter to Insert)"? The below picture is how it looks when typing a date into Word.

[image: Date Example]

I have already gone to the Date & Time option under the Insert menu and the date format that I want is already selected. I think this is only for using quickparts anyway, so the date automatically updates when you open a document. The Region and Language settings under the Control Panel are correct as well.

I thought at one point I found it somewhere under options, but I am sure I looked through everything many times and I can’t find it.

**I posted this exact question at the Microsoft website and someone replied:**
*Go to the Windows Control Panel and click on Clock, Language and Region and then on Change the date, time, or number format and then modify the Short date format so that it is what you want to be used.* **So please don't suggest this again, because in my question I did say that I already tried this and it doesn't work, at least not for Word, in this situation. Thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings in Word Options -> Language.  Just corrected a case where the month was coming in 3 characters on one workstation however all others were getting month spelled out in full. Needed to have English Canada listed first.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  The question is about the year format, not the month.